# What are the Pros and Cons of ICU?

Tags: unicode, globalization, icu

My team is tasked with implementing Unicode in our software, which is well over a million lines of code.  We support an MFC Client and a Server on Windows, AIX or Solaris with an Oracle or SQL Server database.  ICU looks like a very helpful tool.  What are the pros and cons of using ICU?  Does ICU work as advertised without major bugs?

Comment: Yes, ICU works; I've relied on it for years. "Pros and cons" is an opinion question, which is generally considered out of bounds on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6):

A data point:  Our (*yes, that's a disclaimer*) list of users and bugs is all on our [project site](http://icu-project.org).

IMBO (biased): 
**Pros**:

- works as advertised, comprehensive.
- Mature: 10+ years now, with a good stability policy and very active development.
- Uses latest Unicode+CLDR+BCP47+other standards.
- Compiles basically everywhere. C/C++/J and called by/implements python,perl,php,…
- Open source, with an increasing diversity of contributors.
- Comes with all needed data for the above (see below, under cons), yet customizable. (can add custom data)

**Cons**:

- Needs better documentation (*we try- anyone want to help*?).
- Lots of APIs- "it's too big #1" hard to know which one to use, even if it does what you want.
- Used by lots of types of programs, from embedded devices, smartphones through major desktop apps through databases and operating systems and enterprise apps: So, there may be multiple ways to do something.
- Comes with all needed data for the above! "it's too big #2" (see above, under pros), yet customizable. (can be trimmed down to size)

Answer (score 2):

ICU is terrible: avoid if at all possible.

- Despite its age, basic things in it are broken, for example in this question: [Fixing regex to work around ICU/RegexKitLite bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980946/fixing-regex-to-work-around-icu-regexkitlite-bug)
- Time handling is broken as times are underspecified: you can't distinguish a DST from a non-DST time in a reliable way in many APIs.
- It's freaking huge.
- The documentation needs a lot of work. Less-used features are often unusable because there's no way to figure out the right way to use them. I spent days trying to get transliteration to work as explained and eventually gave up.
- It likes to work in UTF-16, the worst of all possible worlds.
- Support is unresponsive to problems.
- In my experience, it's not until you're most of the way through a project that you begin to discover the insidious flaws that will take 90% of your time.

For many people, there is no alternative so you're stuck with it.

Comment: the 'basic thing' is not a bug. Follow the link and the bug.   Did you file a bug or send a support request about transliteration?  ICU is huge because of the feature and *data* set, but can be made smaller in well-documented ways.  Did you file a bug on DST/non-DST? - I'm not sure I understand what's being requested.    Reading SO isn't part of our official support, normally.